# Auto Index match output in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert data manually, i am unable to do auto conversion with excel VBA. Can you please suggest to me as per image how to write a code in excel VBA to auto output with single click.
I need data with one by one as shown an image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTRhe.jpg)

Comment: mind sharing what you had tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpivot an Excel matrix/pivot-table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115219/unpivot-an-excel-matrix-pivot-table)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/excel-macrovba-to-transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows/36366394?r=SearchResults#36366394