# Excel UDF to Unpivot (Melt, Reverse pivot, Flatten, Normalize) blocks of data within Tables

Tags: vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, powerquery, dynamic-arrays

This question will seek multiple approaches `LET/LAMBDA` `VBA UDF` and `Power Query Function`, so there will be no single right answer, but a solicitation of approaches to be used as references.

[Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3576831/scott) raised a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115219/unpivot-an-excel-matrix-pivot-table/67545928?noredirect=1#comment121284336_67545928) about unpivoting a complex table that contains blocks of data instead of individual data points. The basic idea is illustrated in this table:

|  |  | Jan | Jan | Jan | Jan | Feb | Feb | Feb | Feb | Mar | Mar | Mar | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| State | City | Pressure | Temp | Humidity | CO2 | Pressure | Temp | Humidity | CO2 | Pressure | Temp | Humidity | CO2 |
| Georgia | Atlanta | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Massachusetts | Boston | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 |
| Texas | Dallas | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 |
| Louisiana | Jonesboro | 145 | 146 | 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152 | 153 | 154 | 155 | 156 |
| California | San Francisco | 193 | 194 | 195 | 196 | 197 | 198 | 199 | 200 | 201 | 202 | 203 | 204 |

The data for each city is in blocks of four columns containing Pressure, Temperature, Humidity and CO2 (or PTHC). We want to unpivot the PTHC blocks of values according to their month by the State and City. Here is the desired output:

| State | City | month | Pressure | Temp | Humidity | CO2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Georgia | Atlanta | Jan | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Georgia | Atlanta | Feb | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| Georgia | Atlanta | Mar | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Massachusetts | Boston | Jan | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 |
| Massachusetts | Boston | Feb | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 |
| Massachusetts | Boston | Mar | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 |
| Texas | Dallas | Jan | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 |
| Texas | Dallas | Feb | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 |
| Texas | Dallas | Mar | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 |
| Louisiana | Jonesboro | Jan | 145 | 146 | 147 | 148 |
| Louisiana | Jonesboro | Feb | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152 |
| Louisiana | Jonesboro | Mar | 153 | 154 | 155 | 156 |
| California | San Francisco | Jan | 193 | 194 | 195 | 196 |
| California | San Francisco | Feb | 197 | 198 | 199 | 200 |
| California | San Francisco | Mar | 201 | 202 | 203 | 204 |

The order of the rows is not important, so long as they are complete - i.e. the output could be sorted by month, city, state, ... it does not matter. The output does not need to be a dynamic array that spills - i.e. in the case of a Power Query function, it clearly would not be.

It can be assumed that the PTHC block is always consistent, i.e.

- it never skips a field value, e.g. PTHC PTC PTHC...
- it never changes order, e.g. PTHC PCHT

The months are always presented in groups that are equally sized to the block (in this example, 4, so there will be four Jan columns, Feb columns, etc.).  e.g. if there are 7 months, there will be 7 PTHC blocks or 28 columns of data.

> ***However***, the pattern of months can also be interleaved such that the
> months will increment and the PTHC block will be grouped (i.e. PPP
> TTT HHH CCC) like this:

|  |  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Jan | Feb | Mar | Jan | Feb | Mar | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| State | City | Pressure | Pressure | Pressure | Temp | Temp | Temp | Humidity | Humidity | Humidity | CO2 | CO2 | CO2 |

The UDF would also have to accommodate more or less than 4 fields inside the block. The use of Months and PTHC are just illustrations, the attribute that represents months in this example will always be a single row (although a multi-row approach would be an interesting question - but a new and separate one). The attribute that represents the field values PTHC will also be a single row.

> I will propose a LET function based on Scott's question, but there
> certainly can be better approaches and both VBA and Power Query have
> their own strengths. The objective is to create a collection of
> working approaches.

Answer (score 2):

**LET/LAMBDA Approach**

This requires Excel 365. The formula is:

```
=LET( upValues, C3:N7,  upHdr, C2:N2,  upAttr, C1:N1,
      byBody, A3:B7,  byHdr, A2:B2,
      attrTitle, "month",

         upFields, UNIQUE( upHdr,1 ), blockSize, COUNTA( upFields ),
         byC, COLUMNS( byBody ), upC, COLUMNS( upValues ),
         dmxR, MIN( ROWS( upValues ), ROWS( byBody ) ),
         upCells, dmxR * upC/blockSize,
         tCSeq, SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 1 + blockSize ),  tRSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells + 1,, 0 ),  upSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0 ),
         hdr, IF( tCSeq <= byC,  INDEX( byHdr, , tCSeq ),
                 IF( tCSeq = byC + 1, attrTitle,
                     INDEX( upFields, 1, tCSeq - byC - 1 ) ) ),
         muxBody, INDEX( byBody, SEQUENCE( upCells, byC, 0 )/byC/upC*blockSize + 1, SEQUENCE( 1, byC ) ),
         muxAttr, INDEX( upAttr, MOD( SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0, blockSize ), upC ) + 1 ),
         muxValues, INDEX( upValues, SEQUENCE( upCells, blockSize, 0 )/upC+1, MOD(SEQUENCE( upCells, blockSize, 0 ),upC)+1),
         table, IF( tCSeq <= byC, muxBody,
                   IF( tCSeq = byC + 1, muxAttr,
                       INDEX( muxValues, upSeq + 1, tCSeq - byC - 1 ) ) ),
         IF( tRSeq = 0, hdr, INDEX( table, tRSeq, tCSeq) )  )
```

This takes in 6 variables:

- upValues - the data that will be unpivoted in blocks
- upHdr - the header row that contains the PTHC values
- upAttr - the attribute that will be unpivoted i.e. the months row
- byBody - the body of values that will unpivot the values i.e. the State and City values
- byHdr - the header of the byBody (the titles "State" and "City")
- attrTitle - an optional title for the attribute that will be unpivoted

These are better understood in this illustration:

[image: input table structure]

and here it is with the test data and the results shown to make it easier to understand:

[image: result]

The output above can also be illustrated:

[image: output parts]

The red text are the internal variables used to construct the result.

The formula has 5 parts as follows:

[image: parts]

**Taking Dimensions** is obvious - it is simply parameterizing the variables that will be used repeatedly later.  **dmxR** is using the MIN of the rows of either upValues or byBody just in case the user accidentally puts in malformed values and byBody that would otherwise result in a nonsensical output.

**Building Sequences** creates three sequences that will be used for indexing the inputs and outputs:

- **tCSeq** (table column sequence) is a column-wise sequence sized to the final output table that will have byBody + Attribute (month) + values (blocksize) columns.
- **tRSeq** (table row sequence) is a row-wise sequence sized to the final output table that will have dmxR*upC/blocksize + 1 (hdr) rows.
- **upSeq** (unpivot sequence) is a row-wise sequence sized to the final output table that will have dmxR*upC/blocksize rows (no header).

**Create Array Components** uses the dimensions and sequences above to construct the parts of the output table.

- **hdr** (header) is the new header with the labels (State & City), the attribute title (month) and the field names (PTHC).
- **muxBody** (multiplexed byBody) is the repetition of the byBody that is multiplexed across the dmxR rows.
- **muxAttr** (multiplexed upAttr) is the repetition of the upAttr that is multiplexed across the dmxR rows.
- **muxValues** (multiplexed upValues) is a block-wise repetition that will have dmxR*upC/blocksize rows.

The last two lines **stitch** parts together. First, **table** stitches **muxBody**, **muxAttr** and **muxValues** in a column-wise integration using **tCSeq** and a row-wise multiplex using **upSeq**.

Just because it is mentally easier (and easier to test), I separated the row-wise integration (using **tRSeq**) of the **hdr** onto the **table** in the last line.

An alternative to stitching with IF statements is to use IFERROR(INDEX which forces errors and then replaces the errors with the next part of the table, but that is sooo hard to test and debug even when it is only row-wise or column-wise. Put in a combination of row-wise and column-wise, it is a cauchemar.

Answer (score 2):

Powerquery version.  A bit longer code to accommodate possibility of AAAABBBB instead of ABABABAB

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// list of months
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = List.Repeat(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table.FirstN(Source,1), {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value")[Value],Table.RowCount(Source)-2),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), "Index", 0, 1),

// list of PTHC
#"Unpivoted Other Columns2" = List.Repeat(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table.FirstN(Table.Skip(Source,1) ,1), {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value")[Value],Table.RowCount(Source)-2),
#"Converted to Table2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList(#"Unpivoted Other Columns2", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), "Index", 0, 1),

// all other data
#"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table.Skip(Source,2), {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1", "Index", 0, 1),

// merge in months and PTHC
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Index"},#"Converted to Table",{"Index"},"X1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Merged Queries" ,{"Index"},#"Converted to Table2",{"Index"},"X2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded X1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "X1", {"Column1"}, {"Month"}),
#"Expanded X2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded X1", "X2", {"Column1"}, {"Type"}),

//extra work to pivot in correct format
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded X2",{{"Column1", "State"}, {"Column2", "City"}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Attribute","Index"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"State", Order.Ascending}, {"City", Order.Ascending}, {"Month", Order.Ascending}, {"Type", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
TypeCount=List.Count(List.Distinct(#"Added Index1"[Type])), 
#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index1", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, TypeCount), Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Integer-Divided Column", List.Distinct(#"Integer-Divided Column"[Type]), "Type", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: I had not realized that the order of the months would present a challenge in M. I intuitively thought that PQ would make quick work of this without much effort (having invested zero effort myself). Your opening approach is much faster than anything I would have done. I will use your techniques in the future. Normally, I would have stopped at `#"Removed Columns"` for most applications, but bc %Hum is a different data type, we cannot stop there - so your final repivoting is difficult and necessary. Nice job. As I see how you did it, I think hardcoding is inevitable i.e. PQ function = impossible.

Comment: slightly changed code to remove the hardcoded number of PTHC unique  values

Comment: Also, not sure why you say a PQ function is impossible.  All you have to do is feed a range into this as a function and it will work, no coding changes necessary. Order of months is irrelevant

Comment: As I looked through your script, I saw places where M must take on explicit values, so (without having tried to tackle it myself) I thought that this would be very difficult to navigate around. e.g. take this line: `Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded X2",{{"Column1", "State"}, {"Column2", "City"}}),` If the inputs that I defined in my UDF as byHdr were different, such as "Country", "State", "Parish", "City", "Postal Code", how could this be turned into a dynamic function in PQ? Seems super hard to me.

Comment: There is no reason we need to have named columns, though this is hard coded to assume only two columns before the data kicks in, so in that view, you are correct it would be hard to make this dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it can be called an improvement to the existing `LET` solution, but this is both shorter and a little more intuitive to me.

```
=LET( upValues, C3:N7,  upHdr, C2:N2,  upAttr, C1:N1,
      byBody, A3:B7,  byHdr, A2:B2,
      attrTitle, "month",

          attributes, UNIQUE(upAttr,1), attrcount, COUNTA(attributes),
          vars, UNIQUE(upHdr,1), varcount, COUNTA(vars),
          rowseq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(byBody)*attrcount),
          colseq, SEQUENCE(1,varcount+3),
          rept, CEILING(rowseq/attrcount,1),
          rept1, IF(MOD(rowseq, attrcount)=0, attrcount, MOD(rowseq, attrcount)),
          byC, COLUMNS(byBody),
          header, IF(colseq<3, byHdr, IF(colseq=3, attrTitle, INDEX(vars, 1, colseq-byC-1))),
          loc, INDEX(byBody,rept, SEQUENCE(1,byC)),
          attrCol, INDEX(attributes, 1, rept1),
          data, INDEX(upValues, rept, SEQUENCE(1,varcount)+(rept1*varcount)-varcount),
          mydata, IF(colseq<(byC+1), loc, IF(colseq<4, attrCol, INDEX(data, rowseq, colseq-byC-1))),
          final, IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(rowseq)+1)=1, header, INDEX(mydata, SEQUENCE(ROWS(byBody)*attrcount+1)-1, colseq)),
         final )
```

[image]

Comment: Good morning (my time) EDS - This reduces steps by 2. I am still testing it, but you forgot the month column in the output.

Comment: ahh - i just noticed, that you didn't have it in the input - may have missed that point. The original ideas is to unpivot the months, but in blocks of measurements.

Comment: Hey - it fully works and I think it is doing it in less steps. I proposed some edits to parameterize it into a UDF form.