# Convert Horizontal Table Info in Vertical Table With Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple rows of data for different users. Some users have multiple entries and some will only have one. All this info is stored in a '1 row per user' format. My goal is to show all this info vertically, with each user having potentially multiple lines based on how many parameters they pass.

[image: Here is a better, visual representation.] What is the best way to go about this? Ideally, I'd like to have it set up where I can just paste new user entry rows at the bottom and have the vertical table repopulate.

I'm using O365

Comment: Search on here, it has been done.

Comment: As @SolarMike says, it has been done before and I thought that I had done it once. Not quite, but this is similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695983/excel-udf-to-unpivot-melt-reverse-pivot-flatten-normalize-blocks-of-data-wi/68696124#68696124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695983/excel-udf-to-unpivot-melt-reverse-pivot-flatten-normalize-blocks-of-data-wi/68696124#68696124) post:

```
=LET( upValues, B2:G5, upFields, {"ID","Color"},
      byBody, A2:A5,  byHdr, A1,

       blockSize, COLUMNS( upFields ),
       byC, COLUMNS( byBody ), upC, COLUMNS( upValues ),
       dmxR, MIN( ROWS( upValues ), ROWS( byBody ) ),
       upCells, dmxR * upC/blockSize,
       tCSeq, SEQUENCE( 1, byC + blockSize ),  tRSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells + 1,, 0 ),  upSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0 ),

       hdr, IF( tCSeq <= byC,  INDEX( byHdr, , tCSeq ),
                               INDEX( upFields, 1, tCSeq - byC - 0 ) ),
       muxBody, INDEX( byBody, SEQUENCE( upCells, byC, 0 )/byC/upC*blockSize + 1, SEQUENCE( 1, byC ) ),
       muxValues, INDEX( upValues, SEQUENCE( upCells, blockSize, 0 )/upC+1, MOD(SEQUENCE( upCells, blockSize, 0 ),upC)+1),

       table, IF( tCSeq <= byC, muxBody,
                                INDEX( muxValues, upSeq + 1, tCSeq - byC ) ),
       ftable, FILTER( table, INDEX( table, , 2 ) <> 0 ),
       fRSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( ftable ) + 1,,0 ),

       IF( fRSeq = 0, hdr, INDEX( ftable, fRSeq, tCSeq) )  )
```

When unpivoting, we say that we Unpivot rangeX By rangeY. This formula follows that convention.

**upValues** is the values to be unpivoted (B2:G5 in this example). This accepts a range.

**upFields** are the column headers that you want to display in your output *(I hard coded these in because ID# - 1, 2, etc. are essentially ignored in your case)*. This accepts a row-wise range or typed-in row-wise array as shown.

**byBody** is the column of by values *(Jim, Mike...)*. This accepts a column-wise range

**byHdr** is the header for the by column(s). *(Name is only one column, but this accepts a row-wise range)*

As I assume that you want to apply it more generally, I left in a lot of the error handling overhead that was in the original post.

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

This formula work for  Excel 2019 and up

In Cell `I2` array (CSE) formula copied across right to `K2`, and all copied down :

```
  =IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(ISNUMBER($B$2:$G$4),$A$2:$A$4&" "&$B$2:$G$4,"")&IF(ISTEXT($B$2:$G$4),$B$2:$G$4,""))," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&(ROW($A1)*3+COLUMN(A$1))-3&"]"),"")
```

Remark : In Office 365, I think it is a normal entry.

[image]

Comment: Nice work! Incredibly clever use of FILTERXML.

Comment: Amazing formula, thank you!