# How to do Vlookup on Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I am new to working on Excel. I have a Table1 where It shows the product's Quantity with different dates. I need to update the Quantity from Table 1 to Table 2. Is that possible to do using Vlookup.
Can someone Help me to understand how to do it.

Thanks in Advance!

| Product (Table 1) | 01-02-2023 | 01-03-2023 | 01-04-2023 | 01-05-2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB-01-M1 | 0 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| AB-02-M2 | 50 | 10 | 20 | 0 |

| Product (Table 2) | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-02-2023 | 2 |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-03-2023 | 2 |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-04-2023 | 2 |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-05-2023 | 2 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-02-2023 | 2 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-03-2023 | 2 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-04-2023 | 2 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-05-2023 | 2 |

Expected Result:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-02-2023 | 0 |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-03-2023 | 20 |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-04-2023 | 30 |
| AB-01-M1 | 01-05-2023 | 40 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-02-2023 | 50 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-03-2023 | 10 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-04-2023 | 20 |
| AB-02-M2 | 01-05-2023 | 0 |

Comment: Check out xlookup(), not sure it is on Googlesheets though.

Comment: yes you can try with vlookup & match, @SolarMike xlookup works in googlesheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use index(match) to match the dates with the product number to get the values.
I took your sample and placed them side by side on a sheet and used this formula in I2 and dragged it down.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$3,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(H2,B$1:E$1,0))
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your Table2 is merely an unpivoted version of Table1.

In Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 you can create the entire Table2 give Table 1 using Power Query (built-in or available as a free MS supplied add-in in earliest versions).

`Get & Transform` => `Get Data` => `From Table`

Then select the Product column and `Unpivot Other Columns`.

In Microsoft 365, you can also create Table 2 by using a worksheet formula with some of the newer functions.

For example, entered into a single cell:

```
=VSTACK(
    {"Product", "Date", "Value"},
    LET(
        dataRng, CHOOSECOLS(Table1[#Data], SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(Table1) - 1, 2)),
        rowAxis, Table1[Product],
        colAxis, CHOOSECOLS(Table1[#Headers], SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(Table1) - 1, 2)),
        iCol, COLUMN(INDEX(rowAxis, 1, 1)),
        amountCol, TOCOL(dataRng),
        totalCells, COUNTA(amountCol),
        HSTACK(
            INDEX(
                rowAxis,
                INT(SEQUENCE(totalCells, 1, 0, 1) / COLUMNS(dataRng)) + 1,
                BYCOL(INDEX(rowAxis, 1, ), LAMBDA(aCol, COLUMN(aCol) - iCol + 1))
            ),
            INDEX(
                colAxis,
                SEQUENCE(1, ROWS(colAxis), 1, 1),
                MOD(SEQUENCE(totalCells, 1, 0, 1), COLUMNS(dataRng)) + 1
            ),
            amountCol
        )
    )
)
```

Creates:
[image]

from your `Table 1` above

Adapted from the [answer given by @pgSystemTester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115219/unpivot-an-excel-matrix-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
=LET(lk, A1:E3, in, A5:C13, lkdates, TAKE(lk,1),lkProd, TAKE(lk,,1),
 data,DROP(in,1), nQty, MAP(TAKE(data,,1), INDEX(data,,2), LAMBDA(p,d,
  INDEX(FILTER(lk, lkProd=p),,XMATCH(d,lkdates)))),
 HSTACK(DROP(in,,-1), VSTACK("Quantity",nQty)))
```

this is another way of doing it without using array helper function such as `MAP`:

```
=LET(lk,A1:E3,in,A5:C13,lkdates,TAKE(lk,1),lkProd,TAKE(lk,,1),data,DROP(in,1),
 arr, INDEX(lk, XMATCH(TAKE(data,,1), lkProd),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(lk))),
 nQty, INDEX(arr,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),XMATCH(INDEX(data,,2), lkdates)),
 HSTACK(DROP(in,,-1), VSTACK("Quantity", nQty)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The formula only depends on two ranges: `lk`, `in` so it can be easier adjusted to your real problem. The rest of the names are deduced from them, via `DROP`,`TAKE`, and `INDEX`. There are multiple ways of doing it, this is just one of them. We use `MAP` to iterate over the `data` of the first two columns of `data`. We filter the row from `lk` name via `FILTER` by product (`p`), then we take the corresponding column via `INDEX/XMATCH` combination for a given date (`d`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula to unpivot in **Google sheets**.

[image]

---

```
=VSTACK({"Product","Date","Quantity"},
ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A3&"♦"&B1:E1&"♦"&B2:E3),"♦")))
```

---

You can use XLOOKUP & FILTER to get the values.

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$A$3,FILTER($B$2:$E$3,$H2=$B$1:$E$1))
```

---

You can work it out more dynamic way like as below

[image]

---

```
=MAP(G2:G9,H2:H9,LAMBDA(g,h,XLOOKUP(g,$A$2:$A$3,FILTER($B$2:$E$3,h=$B$1:$E$1))))
```

---

In **Excel** you can use **Power Query Tool** to **Unpivot other columns**

[image]

---

1. Select `Table 1`
2. From `Data` Tab => `Get&Transform Data` => `From Table/Range`
3. Paste the `M-Code` in `Advanced Editor` from `Home Tab`

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product (Table 1)", type text}, {"01/02/2023", Int64.Type}, {"01/03/2023", Int64.Type}, {"01/04/2023", Int64.Type}, {"01/05/2023", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Product (Table 1)"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Product (Table 1)", "Product"}, {"Attribute", "Date"}, {"Value", "Quatity"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

5. Click on `Close & Load` to get **Expected Result** in **New Worsheet**

[image]

---

In **Excel** using `VLOOKUP` & `MATCH` Function you can get the expected result

[image]

---

Enter the formula in cell I2 and drag down

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$E$3,MATCH($H2,$A$1:$E$1,0),0)
```

---

In Excel you can use Double XLOOKUP or XLOOKUP & FILTER

[image]

---

Enter the formula in cell I2 to drag down

```
=XLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$A$3,XLOOKUP($H2,$B$1:$E$1,$B$2:$E$3))
```

---

```
=XLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$A$3,FILTER($B$2:$E$3,$H2=$B$1:$E$1))
```

---